# How to avoid Meteor helpers run multiple times

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my template I have this HTML:

```
<input id="name"   type="text" value="{{card.name}}">
<input id="prefix" type="text" value="{{card.prefix}}">
<input id="phone"  type="tel"  value="{{card.phone}}">
```

and this JavaScript

```
Template.cardForm.helpers({
  card: function() {
    return getCard();
  }
});

var getCard = function() {
    console.log("I'm here !!!");
    return Cards.findOne({_id: cardId});
}
```

When I run my app, the `console.log` shows "I'm here !!!" 3 times, and I think that `Ecards.findOne()` is executing 3 times.

How can I Avoid those extra calls?

I want to get card object in order to fill `{{card.name}}`, `{{card.prefix}}` and `{{card.phone}}`, but only with one call to `getCard()`.

Answer (score 3):

The `card` helper is executed several times since `card` is present in evaluated template code more than once.

A pattern to avoid duplicate calls in scenarios like the one you're facing is to use `#with`:

```
{{#with card}}
  <input id="name"   type="text" value="{{name}}">
  <input id="prefix" type="text" value="{{prefix}}">
  <input id="phone"  type="tel"  value="{{phone}}">
{{/with}}
```

This will call `card` once and then run the nested code in the context of its result.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If it solves the issue, you can mark the answer as correct.