# Avoid repeating queries in meteor template helpers

Tags: meteor

I'm starting to use meteor for a project, and there are several concepts that are being pretty hard to me coming from angular+php.

I'm trying to handle two helpers, for displaying a list of records in a table, based in a date range that I'm storing on a session variable. My template then looks like this, I'm using a helper called noRecords and another called records, records store the actual document set, and in noRecords I'm trying to store as a boolean whether the record document set is empty or not.

```
    div(class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2')
        if noRecords
            p There are no records for the selected date 
        else
            table(class='table table-bordered')
                thead
                    tr  
                        td Id
                        td Name

                tbody
                    each records
                        +record
```

Unfortunately I've not being able to set records and noRecords at the same time without repeating the query, in my javascript code those helpers are now defined like this:

```
records : function(){
    var startDate = Session.get('searchDate').setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var endDate = Session.get('searchDate').setHours(23,59,59,999);
    var matches = Records.find(
                    {date : { 
                                $gte : new Date(startDate),
                                $lte : new Date(endDate)
                            }
                    });
    return records;
},

noRecords : function(){
    var startDate = Session.get('searchDate').setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var endDate = Session.get('searchDate').setHours(23,59,59,999);
    var matches = Records.find(
                    {date : { 
                                $gte : new Date(startDate),
                                $lte : new Date(endDate)
                            }
                    });
    return records.count() === 0;
}
```

The date session variable is set by an event.

I guess there must be a better way of doing this instead of executing the query twice, I've tried using reactive variables but I had no luck, since I can't make the reactive variable to update when the minimongo query executes.

Is there any way of achieving this without running two queries?

Comment: Er, `function getValues() { return /*whatever array of values you want */}`? Asking for a "cleanest way" is off-topic as it is opinion-based though (you may want to rephrase that), but the usual solution to reduce code duplication is to wrap it in a function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've edited my question but my worries are more about executing the query twice more than writing it twice, wrapping it in a function still makes it to execute twice. Sorry if it was not very clear.

Comment: You can use `with` to get the records and if their count is positive, iterate. Otherwise, show the `no records` paragraph. I have answered a similar (albeit simpler) question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33464551/268093).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are repeating the same logic in multiple helpers one solution is to reduce them to a single helper and return an object from it, e.g.:

```
records : function(){
    var startDate = Session.get('searchDate').setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var endDate = Session.get('searchDate').setHours(23,59,59,999);
    var cursor = Records.find(
                    {date : { 
                                $gte : new Date(startDate),
                                $lte : new Date(endDate)
                            }
                    });
    return {
      cursor: cursor,
      empty: cursor.count() === 0,
      one: cursor.count() === 1
    }
}
```

And in your template:

```
if records.one
  p Found One!
```

Silly example but it can be used more broadly.

Note that in your example you wouldn't actually need the `noRecords` helper because your template can check for an empty cursor:

```
each records
  p date
else
  p No records!
```

Comment: The last code example will call the `records` helper twice if there are records. You probably meant something else.

Comment: ah that's right, you wouldn't even need if-each-else, you just need each-else. i'll edit to improve the answer (both will work)

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Blaze, you could use the `{{#each records}}...{{else}}...{{/each}}` using your `records` helper only like this.

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>

  {{#each records}}{{> showRecord}}

  {{else}}<p>There are no records for the selected date</p>

  {{/each}}

  </div>
</template>
```

You could also use `{{#if records}}...{{else}}...{{/if}}` since `each` will iterate over each item in the `records` cursor

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>

  {{#if records}}

     <table class='table table-bordered'>

     <thead>
       <tr>  
           <td>Id</td>
           <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      {{#each}}{{> showRecord}}{{/each}}
      </tbody>

      </table>

  {{else}}<p>There are no records for the selected date</p>

  {{/with}}

  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: As far as I know, `#with` does not iterate its input. Moreover, your second code example has several issues. Can you point to something that shows that `#with` performs iteration?

Comment: That was a mistake, i meant `#each`